# Search a range for a string- check if string of the cell beside matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-drive

The title is a bit weird I admit.

Okay:

- Cells B:B contain a single character
- Cells C:C contain strings
- Cells D:D contain a single character
- Cells E:E contain strings

Cell F1 wants to return "YES" if it can find a cell in C:C that matches the value of E1, that also contains the value of D1 in B:B beside it.

Example:

- Cell B1 contains "E"
- Cell C1 contains "Alpha"
- Cell D1 contains "F"
- Cell E1 contains "Alpha"

F1 returns "".

If you add:

- Cell B2 contains "F"
- Cell C2 contains "Alpha"

F1 returns "YES".

The problem I am having is having the formula check the value of a cell relative to another cell.

Ideally I'd try:

```
=IF((ISNA(MATCH(E2, C:C, ))), "YES", "")
```

but I also want it to check a relative cell for an additional value which is making my brain hurt.

Comment: Are you unable to use two helper columns in which to first perform concatenations of the strings in columns B and C and also in columns D and E? That would be by far the most efficient method. If for whatever reason you are unable (or unwilling) to do this, then you will need an array formula, which will increase calculation time considerably, particularly if the number of rows in which the search  needs to be performed is quite large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works for you. Enter formula into cell **F1**

```
{=IF(SUM((D1=B:B)*(D1<>0)*(E1=C:C)*(E1<>0))>0,"YES","")}
```

Leave out the curly braces and enter the function using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, as XOR LX mentioned above, it is an array formula and will take longer to evaluate. I suggest *not* using whole column references. Below is an example that will work if you have up to 1000 columns of data, which will be much faster.

```
{=IF(SUM((D1=$B$1:$B$1000)*(D1<>0)*(E1=$C$1:$C$1000)*(E1<>0))>0,"YES","")}
```

Comment: Apologies, I made a number of changes to the formula. It should now work

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I apologize but what does the "<>" do?

Comment: `D1<>0` means D1 *is not equal* to zero. Mathematically, you are accepting numbers that are greater than (<) or less than (>) zero, hence by deduction you accept all values not equal to 0. I included this so that the formula wouldn't match on empty cells